# cmdstanr: how to set initial values

Tags: initialization, mcmc, stan

I am having trouble when I want to set initial values for parameters in a Stan program for MCMC using `cmdstanr`.
The relevant guidance in the documentation states that the value passed to the argument `init`in the `cmdstanr`instruction `sample` should in this case be:

> A list of lists containing initial values for all or some parameters. For MCMC the list should contain a sublist for each chain. For optimization and variational inference there should be just one sublist. The sublists should have named elements corresponding to the parameters for which you are specifying initial values. See Examples.

For illustration I am using the following simple Stan program from Rstudio

```
 data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  vector[N] y;
}

 parameters {
  real mu;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
}

 model {
  y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
```

I read the Stan program into R with
`mod <- cmdstan_model(file)`
and then if  I run this code using `sample` thus

```
N <- as.integer(500) 
y <- rnorm(N)
data_list <- list(
  N = N,
  y = y
)

fit <- mod$sample(  
  data = data_list,
  chains = 1,   
  iter_sampling = 2000
)
```

I get perfectly reasonable results but if I try to set initial values of `mu` and `sigma` thus:

```
fit1 <- mod$sample( 
  data = data_list,
  chains = 1,    
  iter_sampling = 2000,
  init = list(
    list(mu = 0.5),
    list(sigma = 0.5) 
    ) 
)
```

I get this error message:

`Error: 'init' has the wrong length. See documentation of 'init' argument.`

I am very new to `cmdstanr` and I expect that I am making a silly mistake, but I can't see what I have done wrong.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think the issue is where you're naming the variables. `init = list(mu = list( 0.5),sigma =  list(0.5))` Given said that, here is a very active forum for stan questions in https://discourse.mc-stan.org/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you are nesting lists. See fixed code below:

```
library(cmdstanr)

stan_code <- ' data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  vector[N] y;
}

 parameters {
  real mu;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
}

 model {
  y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}'

N <- as.integer(500) 
y <- rnorm(N)
data_list <- list(
  N = N,
  y = y
)

mod <- cmdstan_model(stan_file=write_stan_file(stan_code))

fit1 <- mod$sample( 
  data = data_list,
  chains = 1,    
  iter_sampling = 2000,
  init = list(
    list(
    mu = 0.5,
    sigma = 0.5)
  ) 
)
```